# matching multiple values from separate sheets in excel

Tags: excel

I have two sheets of data I need to match and transfer values with.

First two columns 1A & 1B

Column 1A contains all unique numbers (these are invoice numbers that we bill out to our customers)
Column 1B contains revenues when we receive payment for these jobs.

second two columns 2A & 2B

I have started to scan our check reports and transfer the data into a simple two column excel sheet (2A & 2B) Column A contains invoice numbers that are also contained in column 1A, column 2B contains the data I want to be transferred into column 1B for each corresponding match between columns 1A & 2A.

I have done some digging and cannot seem to find a simple solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP is the solution.The formula to do this would go into  sheet 1, Col B , Row 2 (Assuming you have a headers in row 1).

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2, sheet2!A:B,2,false)
```

The formula works like so

```
    VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)

-lookup_value  = a cell you want to lookup  
-table_array = a range of columns with the lookup column in col1
-index_num  = the column you want to return as an int ( in this case column 2)
-range_lookup = should be false to ensure an EXACT match
```